# EKS Cluster Auto Scaler Managed Node group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, autoscaling

I have some difficulty to create cluster auto scale in managed node group. below are nodes worker node setup and configuration.

1. Two worker node exists in same region with t3.medium
2. And one worker node has label name with (mms-node-group)
3. when I'm deploying below YAML file pod initially in running state.
4. Then I will scale-in deployment count kubectl scale --replicas=2 deployment/mms pod going to pending state
5. kubectl describe pod logs are below.

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mms
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mms
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - mms-node-group
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - mms
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            namespaces:
            - default
      containers:
      - name: mms
        image: mms:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 900m
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: mms
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: deployment
    name: mms
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 2
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 20
```

pod status with single replicas count

```
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mms-6f4f57d888-mv45v   1/1     Running   0          23m
```

scale the pod

```
kubectl scale --replicas=2 deployment/mms
```

pod status with two replicas count

```
mms-6f4f57d888-mv45v   1/1     Running   0          23m
mms-6f4f57d888-xx5vb   0/1     Pending   0          18m
```

pod describe logs

```
 Warning  FailedScheduling   27m (x3 over 28m)     default-scheduler   0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity, 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules.
  Warning  FailedScheduling   24m                   default-scheduler   0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules, 2 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity.
  Warning  FailedScheduling   21m                   default-scheduler   0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules, 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity.
```

Could you please help me on this

Comment: Have you checked cluster autoscaler logs? It prints in the output how it makes decisions on whether to scale or not to scale. Also, the node label `app=mms-node-group` must be a part of the node definition so that it automatically applied when a new node joins the cluster.